# How to pass and compare strings Correctly JavaScript

Tags: javascript, jquery, string

I'm getting an error on the if statement - it can't make the compare ('unexpected indentifier')
but I can't figure out why.
I'm guessing it has to do with the fact that "table" is not a string object.. 
**This code is implemented inside a C code so you should Ignor The "\n" and the " signs**

```js
              "function postRow(i,table){\n"

                "var desc=document.getElementsByName('description'+table);\n"
                "var inter=document.getElementsByName('logInterval'+table);\n"  
                
                "if( table.equals('AN') || table.equals('OW') ){\n"
                  "var mu=document.getElementsByName('mul'+table);\n"
                  "var di=document.getElementsByName('div'+table);\n"
                  "var off=document.getElementsByName('offset'+table);\n"
               "$.post('',{func:'saveTable'+table,\n"
                            "index:i,\n"
                            "description:desc[i].value,\n"
                            "logInterval:inter[i].value,\n"
                            "mul:mu[i].value,\n"
                            "div:di[i].value,\n"
                            "offset:off[i].value,\n"  
                        "});"
                "}\n"
                
                "else if (table.equals('DG') ){\n"
                  "var count=document.getElementsByName('counterDG');\n"
                  "$.post('',{func:'saveTable'+table,\n"
                            "index:i,\n"
                            "description:desc[i].value,\n"
                            "logInterval:inter[i].value,\n"
                            "counter:count[i].value,\n"
                       "});\n"                 
                "}\n"

                "setTimeout(updateTable(table),1000);"     
                "}\n"
```

Calling the function:

```js
onclick=postRow(i,"DG");
```

Comment: Where is the error ?

Comment: Sorry, I will edit the post :-)

Comment: Why dont you actually remove all the \n and " just for us to easily read it? This makes it harder to read. What does `tables.equals()` do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Javascript strings don't have an `.equals()` method. Use the `===` operator:

```
if (table === 'AN' || table === 'OW')
```

Comment: I tried it at the beginning and it didn't work.. I'll try again

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using table.equals('AN'), use table == ('AN').